# Как получить объект класса родителя?

Tags: java

Я написал самую простую функцию в классе *person*.
Функция получает параметр **msg** и выводит его в консоль.

```
public class person {
    int height;
    float weight;

    void talk(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Также есть три созданных объекта с параметрами, класса *person*.

```
person max = new person();
        max.height = 189;
        max.weight = 54.5f;

        person oleg = new person();
        oleg.height = 154;
        oleg.weight = 65.4f;

        person andrew = new person();
        andrew.height = 169;
        andrew.weight = 61.2f;
```

Другая функция связанная с классом *person*.

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String isMsg = scanner.nextLine();
        oleg.talk(isMsg);
```

Моя задача: Мне нужно получить объект, который передаёт параметр в функцию **talk()**. Функция выведет то что было занесено в переменную **isMsg**. Так как объектов более одного, мне нужно получить также и имя объекта.

Вот например этот:

```
oleg.talk(isMsg);
```

Comment: Объект не передает параметр в ф-ю. Вызывается ф-я объекта (экземпляра класса).

Comment: @Kromster Принял.

Comment: Не понятно, ничего

Comment: @ScruffytheJanitor мне нужно получить кто именно вызывает функцию. Точнее какой объект.

Comment: Допустим вы можете получить. Как вы хотите в дальнейшем это использовать (какой конечный результат вы хотите получить)? Отредактируйте вопрос, дополните его желаемым поведением кода

Comment: Метод`talk` вызывается для известного экземпляра класса `Person`, информация о названии внешней переменной `oleg` для класса недоступна.  Можете добавить строковое поле `name` в класс `Person`: `Person oleg = new Person("oleg"); `